# How to change default jar icon

Tags: java, jar, icons

First I have read all questions about this subject, so this is not a repeated question.

What I want to ask about, how an application written in Java (such as eclipse) uses an icon instead of the default jar icons.

I don't care about compatibility, I always can make 2 different versions of my program to Windows and Linux.

How to make it in Linux and Windows.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the case of programs like eclipse, which are written in java and have a specific icon in Windows (or Linux or Mac for that matter), they actually have an OS specific executable file, e.g. eclipse.exe for windows, that initialises the java program.

It is this executable that contains the application icon, not the Java program. If you want to do the same, you'll need to create the executable 'front door', as it were, and give it an icon.

If it's just for your own personal aesthetics, just create a short cut to the jar file and change the icon of the shortcut.

Comment: great hint regarding the icon for a java application; my question would be how can I do that 'front door' executable with the icon on it? Would it need to be a .net exe that just launches my .jar file? how can that be done?

Comment: @gadget00 My .net knowledge is very limited unfortunately, you might have to do some more googling on that.

Answer (score 5):

To set an image for MAC, you can use `com.apple.eawt.Application`. try this:

```
Image img = new ImageIcon("abc.png").getImage();  // your desired image  
Application app = Application.getApplication();
app.setDockIconImage(img);
```

However, this will not build on Windows or Linux by default. If you'd like it to, (Maven) add the following dependency to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yuvimasory</groupId>
    <artifactId>orange-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or, if you don't use Maven, you can download the JAR from `http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/yuvimasory/orange-extensions/1.3.0/orange-extensions-1.3.0.jar`

Comment: Where is this code use in maven java swing netbean project?

Answer (score 3):

If the application is launched using [Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml), an application icon can be specified for use in desktop shortcuts and menu items.

Note that this icon is not attached directly to the Jar, but since the end user never sees or has to deal with a Jar, that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I use NetBeans, so if you aren't using that, I don't quite know. But, when you select the window, there is an option in the properties window for an icon file. When you build the .jar, that icon should be built in with the program.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stick with eclipse as I'm using SWT and WindowBuilder plugins.

Comment: So i use NetBeans also and when i look in the properties window for a JFrame i created with the IDE i see iconImage and iconImages. the options are <none> and <default> when i click on the ... its not as simple as selecting an icon file... :(

Comment: You have to select the option for "custom code," or something like that. The popup box will allow you to enter the java code to load the image file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the actual application icon in, say, Windows, you can't change it (programmatically). That's determined by the OS. Although you can change it in your OS in Folder Options.

You can, however, set the window (read: JFrame) icon image using `setIconImage()`.